# How to ffmpeg livestream video from link google drive?

Tags: ffmpeg, google-drive-api

How to ffmpeg livestream video from link google drive?

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
for /F "delims=;" %%F in (linkdrive.txt) DO ffmpeg -re -i "%%F" -ar 44100 -vcodec copy -f flv "out.mp4"
```

Comment: What's the contents of linkdrive, specifically what form of URLs?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mLt58jjhwtNUI7wur8OcwjkvJyuuQEdC -@Mulvya

Answer (score 0):

Livestreaming is simply not supported in Drive API.

Comment: Oh. Thank u @noogui